# Angular JS routing issue with cakephp framework

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cakephp, angular-routing

I am new to the AngularJS and facing the critical issue right now in my project.The issue is when there is any third argument in my URL and if I refresh the page then the that third argument is gone and page goes to the default route. 
I am using `ngRoute` in my project.My `app.js` file contains following routing :

```
when('/lifejournals/journallistview/:id', {
                templateUrl: _ROOT + 'lifejournals/journallistview'
            }).
```

For Example right now my URL is `localhost/lifejournals/` . So in that lifejournals is controller name of cakephp and index is the action.

Now I click on something and my route will be

```
localhost/lifejournals/journallistview/34
```

So it will also work fine for the first time.But when i refresh the page then my third parameter is got blanked and URL looks like

```
 /lifejournals/journallistview.
```

Please help to sovle it out.